# Low level Eldritch Knight or Bladesinger for front line

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, eldritch-knight

I’m starting a new low level 5e campaign, level 3.  The other two players are a cleric, and a non-melee warlock.  We need another front-line tank.  Which would be better at low level  (level 3-8)  for consistent front-line tank, an Eldritch Knight or Bladesinger? Why?

Comment: This feels rather broad and opinion-based. Better how? Better at not dying? Better at hitting things with melee weapons? Better close-quarters damage output? Better at offering control options to keep enemies off the back-liners?

Comment: Another question would be, why do you need a tank? And what do you think a tank actually does in D&D?

Comment: Which could stay front line the longest without dying.

Comment: Which could do more melee damage

Comment: Which could do a better job keeping Enemies off back line casters

Comment: @Shaxcat this site has pretty tight requirements for how questions are asked. However if you edit your question  to include your above comments (specifically the last one) to make it clear *exactly* what you mean, I think the question should get reopened in a jiffy.

Comment: Typically for tanks it is much more important to stand in front and survive than to deal melee damage. They are not primarily damage dealers, they are primarily attack sinks. They just need to be competent enough in dealing damage to be perceived as a threat.